# Need help with this Symbolic Logic Proof please

Tags: logic, proof, symbolic-logic

I am having trouble solving this proof. Line 5 is wrong, I know it's Demorgan's Law, but the proof machine doesn't accept that as an answer. I think it only accepts ~Elim, vElim, vIntro, ~Intro, &Intro, etc.[image]

Comment: Try using ~~P and ~~Q in 5. I think you are doing too much in one step by directly turning ~~P into P.

Comment: Disjunction Elim on the first premise: derive P in both cases.